# copy orders of a customer to other customer in magento

Tags: extensions

Is it possible to fetch all the orders of a customer and copy into other customer in magento?

Comment: You want to copy them - not just move? E.g. the orders are still available under the old customer's account, but are now also available under the new customer's account, too?

Comment: Do you mean the cart contents? So to send them over to a co-worker so he can finish the order? That would probably be useful, but I dont know how to do that. I just want to help and clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks philwinkle and sorry for ambiguity in my question. i need to move orders of a customer to other customer account, orders will not be available in old customer account. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways to handle this -

1. Edit the database directly. **Don't do this**.
2. Create a one-off script that will reassociate orders with other customers.

To do so, you can run something akin to:

```
$fromCustomer = $customer->loadByEmail('fromemail@host.net');
$toCustomer = $customer->loadByEmail('toemail@host.net');

$orderEmailCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',$fromCustomer->getEmail());
$orderIdCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$fromCustomer->getId());

foreach($orderEmailCollection as $order){
    $order->setCustomerId($toCustomer->getId());
    $order->setCustomerEmail($toCustomer->getEmail());
    $order->save();
}

foreach($orderIdCollection as $order){
    $order->setCustomerId($toCustomer->getId());
    $order->setCustomerEmail($toCustomer->getEmail());
    $order->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot philwinkle. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: This one saved so much manual work in the database :) Thankees!

Answer (score 1):

There's this script:

https://github.com/iateadonut/magento_copy_customer

It grabs a customer and all his orders through the single command:

$mg->copy_customer(1234);

if 1234 is the customer_entity.entity_id - You can take a look in the source code to see how the table restraints were queried to make sure all rows were grabbed.

There are other methods in there that should be able to move an order for you.  You could fork it and give your work to others or ask the author to build something specific.